# Must all java class file belong to a java package?

Tags: java

It seems there a 'default package' in eclipse.
What's it?

Comment: A class with no package statement is in the default package which is the top level directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving a class without a package, i.e. in the default package, is fine if you're just hacking something up for an example or something.

However, as soon as you start adding more and more classes without packages you'll soon find things getting messy.

The main reason not to use the default package is the potential for conflicts with other code. This is where it is helpful to use the "reverse domain name" style of package naming such as "com.stackoverflow.utils.MagicConverter".

Use packages.

Answer (score 2):

The default package is for classes that do not have any package declared. However this is discouraged (eclipse warns you) - you can't import these classes.